# Text is not displayed on Bubbles in Bubble Chart

Tags: dc.js

I've a bubble chart built using dc.js in which the texts are not shown on the bubbles. Also, is there is a way to rotate the text on the bubbles.

Here is my code.

```
wfAvgChartBubble
        .width(658)
        .height(400)
        .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 60})
        .dimension(wfStatusNameAvgDimBubble)
        .group(wfStatusNameAvgGroupBubble)
        .colors(d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10))
        .keyAccessor(function (p) {
            return p.value.total;
        })
        .valueAccessor(function (p) {
            return p.value.avg;
        })
        .radiusValueAccessor(function (p) {
            return p.value.avg;
        })
        .x(d3.scaleBand().domain(data.map( function(d) {
            return d['workflow_status_name'];
        }
         )))
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        //.x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 5000]))
        .r(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 9000]))
        .minRadiusWithLabel(15)
        .elasticY(true)
        .yAxisPadding(150)
        .elasticX(true)
        .xAxisPadding(300)
        .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.07)
        .title(function (p) {
               return p.key
                       + "\n"
                       + "Total Records: " + p.value.total + "\n"
                       + "Average Time Taken: " + p.value.avg;
           })
        .render();
```

I need to print the text on each bubble

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### showing all the labels

It would be easier to test this with a running example, but I think your problem is this line:

```
    .minRadiusWithLabel(15)
```

From your screenshot (thanks!) it looks like the big bubble has its label (which defaults to the key) but the labels are missing on the smaller bubbles. Try

```
    .minRadiusWithLabel(0)
```

to display labels no matter what size the bubble.

<sup>[(minRadiusWithLabel docs)](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.bubbleMixin.html#minRadiusWithLabel)</sup>

#### rotating the text

Since the text [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) isn't driven by the data, it's best just to use CSS to change it, unless you need to change them individually.

Here's a [reference to some of the relevant dc.js selectors](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/Chart-selectors).

From there we can infer a CSS rule like

```
g.node text {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```